How to mimic Photo.app skew interaction on iPhone/iPad?
I am trying to mimic the skew interactions of Photo.app on iPhone. I was using CATransform3DMakeRotation but haven't really been able to implement it.
Looks like the photo is rotated from one side in the beginning and scaled up at the same time, and at some point, the rotation axis also moved to the other part of the photo.
Any hint will be appreciated!



You'll want to look at CATransform3D
Here's a quick example to get you on your way...
Using this 300x300 image:

class PerspectiveVC: UIViewController {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "test") else { fatalError("could not load test image") }
        
        imgView.image = img
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width),
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
    var transformToggle: Bool = false
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let layer = imgView.layer
        
        transformToggle.toggle()
        
        if transformToggle {

            // create "rotate on x-axis" transform
            var perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
            perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500
            perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, 45.0 * .pi / 180.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            
            // create "scale on y-axis" transform (3x)
            let scaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 3.0, 0.0)

            // concatentate the two transforms
            let finalTransform = CATransform3DConcat(scaleTransform, perspectiveTransform)
            
            // apply the transform
            layer.transform = finalTransform
            
        } else {
            
            // reset the transform
            layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            
        }
    }
    
}

Starts like this:

tapping anywhere toggles the transform on/off:

